# Array not being emptied

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the following I am trying to map out an array of objects, and if the input matches the first couple characters of a certain array's name then it gets pushed into a new array. But for some reason it is pushing the correct one, but then it still contains the other objects in the array but they're just empty. Is there any way to completely remove them?

```
let newReceipts = receipt.map((found, index) => {
  let foundReceipts = [];
  if (input.toLowerCase() === found.person.substring(0,input.length).toLowerCase()) {
    foundReceipts.push(found);
    console.log('input: ' + input.toLowerCase() + 'found: ' + found.person.substring(0,input.length).toLowerCase());
  } else if (input.toLowerCase() !== found.person.substring(0,input.length).toLowerCase()) {
    console.log('no matches');
  }
  return foundReceipts;
});
console.log(newReceipts);
```

Expected log: `[Array[1]]`

Actual log: `[Array[1], Array[0], Array[0]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of
> calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

In your case the `receipt` array probably has three objects, so each time the condition is satisfied the `foundReceipts` array is appended with the `found` object and then the  `foundReceipts` is itself added to the resulting output array.

When the condition is not satisfied the `foundReceipts` ***still gets added***, but this time the `found` object is *not appended* to the `foundReceipts` array. So this is why you see three elements in the final array.

You can even examine your output `[Array[1], Array[0], Array[0]]`, here it clearly shows that the first time the `if` was satisfied and in subsequent time it wasn't so the empty array was included in the result.

To correctly do this use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
let newReceipts = receipt.reduce((foundReceipts, found, index) => {
  if (input.toLowerCase() === found.person.substring(0,input.length).toLowerCase()) {
    foundReceipts.push(found);
    console.log('input: ' + input.toLowerCase() + 'found: ' + found.person.substring(0,input.length).toLowerCase());
  } else if (input.toLowerCase() !== found.person.substring(0,input.length).toLowerCase()) {
    console.log('no matches');
  }
  return foundReceipts;
}, []);
console.log(newReceipts);
```